# Regex confution

Tags: regex

I know that there are a lot of topics like this one. I've spent a lot of hours checking expressions to make my code work. I don't really understand how regex work, so I hope you can help me out.

I want to validate this inputs (I hope I am not pushing it)

- Only letters (with latin characters too)
- Address (including dots, commas, colon, number sign and hyphen)
- Telephone (numbers and hyphen)

like:

```
/[a-zA-ZÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]+$/          /* Only letters */
/[a-zA-Z0-9\sñáéíóúü .,:#-]+$/    /* Address */
/^[\d-]+$/                        /* Telephone */
```

They work fine, when I include an special character at the end of the string but if I enter that special character between accepted characters it does not work. Allow me to write an example please:

For the "Only letters" expression:

- `ab[(%` - Does not pass
- `a[(%b` - It pass and it shouldn't!

Thanks a lot for your time, any help will be appreciate!

Comment: You forgot the `^` at the beginning of the 2 first patterns. See [`^[a-zA-ZÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/xK8uN5/1). Same with `^[a-zA-Z0-9\sñáéíóúü.,:#-]+$` (where you have a literal space and `\s`, so literal space can be removed). Does it now work as expected?

Comment: I posted my answer with explanations.

Comment: Thank you str stribizhev. Let me try it out, and I will let you know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `^` start of string anchor at the beginning of the 2 first patterns.

See [demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/xK8uN5/1):

```
^[a-zA-ZÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú]+$
^
```

Same with the second regex. There, you also have a literal space and `\s`, so literal space can be removed:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\sñáéíóúü.,:#-]+$
^
```

See [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/xK8uN5/2)

And as for your third regex, it is not optimal since it will match `----1123`.

Use

```
/^(?:\d+-)+\d+$/
```

See [demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/xK8uN5/3). Here, we match sequences of digits and hyphen (with `(?:\d+-)+`) and then a sequence of digits, from beginning till end.

Comment: I am trying to better understand your solution using https://regexr.com/  which say your solutions "no matches found". Why is this?

Comment: ...maybe regexr does not recognize Spanish chars?

Comment: @JeffBezos No idea what your test looks like. Please share the exact saved fiddle. Better, share the exact code you are using the regex in, it will make more sense and will be much more helpful. If you are using it in JS, use jsfiddle.net. For other languages, ideone.com or rextester.com are good.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `/[..]+$/` says that the test subject must have any of the characters (..) **at its end**. `$` symbolises the end of the string. The beginning of the string does not have to match. If you want to enforce that for the entire string, use the beginning anchor as well:

```
/^[..]+$/
```

This now says the string must have any of the characters (..) between its beginning and end, and there's no room for anything else.

You're already doing this for the telephone regex.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try it!